# Label overlapping in Stata13

Tags: label, stata, scatter-plot, overlapping

I am creating scatter plots in Stata 13 to represent data graphically. I want to add labels to my data points, but since I'm usually working with around 30 data points, there are some labels that overlap in my graph. I know that there are some functions available which I can use to change the angle or alignment of my labels manually, but I want to write some sort of code in my do-file so that the overlapped labels change position automatically.

I did some research and I can't find a code or function that do this automatically, because I need a code that address the following options:

- Move the labels of two data points with the same coordinates
- Move the labels of data points with coordinates that are almost the same
- BUT one must still be able to see which label and data point correlate with each other.

Please see my code below.  I've changed some values and labels in the data sheet, because I'm not allowed to share real life data.

```
clear all

*Changing the directory in order to import the correct data sheet
cd "C:\Users\JannekeS\Desktop\Excel data"

*Importing
import excel Name Rate Amount using DataSheet.xlsx

*Creating the Scatter and Labels
scatter Rate Amount, mlabel(Name)
```

Comment: Your difficulty is clear. But there is no code here to comment on as your code fragment conveys nothing more than your use of the `mlabel()` option to show marker labels, as the question naturally implies. The one solution I can recall is an `egen` function `mlabvpos()` from `egenmore` (SSC). The bottom line here is that this problem is easy to recognise but hard to solve in generality. As your problem boils down to wanting code but showing none, by tough criteria this is off-topic here without non-trivial code and a minimal reproducible example. (Nothing stops you inventing data.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve